# Linux command line - Remove 2 characters before each tab for a certain line in a text file

Tags: perl, command-line, sed, grep, cut

I have a tab-delimited text file. The second line is a row of column headers. I want to reproduce the file but removing the last two characters from each column header, except the first one. The first character I want to remove is always a period and the second character is always a number, but can be different numbers (see example below). I need to accomplish this in Linux command line to streamline my analysis. Perhaps using some combination of sed, perl, grep, cut, or some other command?

For example,

I have:

```
Constructed data file 
Data    s123.4  s567.8  s901.2 
abcd    123456  789012  345678 
efgh    901234  567890  123456 
ijkl    789012  345678  901234
```

And I want:

```
Constructed data file
Data    s123    s567    s901
abcd    123456  789012  345678
efgh    901234  567890  123456
ijkl    789012  345678  901234
```

I know this can be done in MS Excel by:
1. Enter a new row between Row 2 & 3
2. Copy column name from A2 to A3
3. In B3 enter =LEFT(B2, LEN(B2)-2)
4. Apply formula across whole row
5. Copy row & paste as values
6. Delete original Row 2

But of course it would be a lot faster in the Linux command line!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please elaborate what your question is? Also, here is a quick tour to get you upto speed with SO - http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/\.\d\b//g if $. == 2' file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `$. == 2`: Checks if the current line is line number 2.
- `s/\.\d\b//g`: Remove all `.NUM` at the end of words

Comment: You should change back tics after the `2` with single quote `2'`

Comment: I ended up using `perl -pe 's/\.\d\b//g if $. == 2' input.txt > output.txt` (incorporating the correction from Jotne). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Through GNU sed,

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/\1/g' file
```

For only second line try this,

```
sed -r '2s/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/\1/g' file
```

Comment: how about `sed -r 's/\.([0-9]+)//g' file`

Comment: yep nice, but it would be `sed -r '2s/\.([0-9]+)//g' file`

Comment: This worked perfectly in Linux! However, in my question I didn't take into account that I also wanted to be able to use the command on a remote Mac OSX, and apparently OSX has issues with sed -r, so I couldn't use this solution after all.

Comment: If you want to use it for OSX then try this, `sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/\1/g' file` For second line `sed '2s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/\1/g' file`